# Multi column index on nested data

Tags: postgresql, database-design, performance, postgresql-performance

I have a table that has a field `user` and a field `group` (among others). Each `user` is in exactly one `group`, not more, not less. Whenever I query for a `user`, I also know his `group`. Would it be faster to have a multi-column index and query for both, `user` and `group`, instead of just using a single-column index and querying only for the `user`? If yes, what index type would I choose? My idea was, that searching for the `group` first and then searching for the `user` only in those results would be fastest, but I'm not sure if any of the index types can actually do that.

I also thought about separating `users` and `groups` by putting them in different tables but as both numbers can grow indefinitely, I couldn't think of a way to do that without having an indefinite number of tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm mostly familiar with MySQL and MS SQL, so I can't speak to the performance of PostgreSQL on multi-column indexes.  However, my guess is that as long as the number of users is small (< 100,000), a single-column index on user would work well.

Regarding the second portion of your question:

> I also thought about separating users and groups by putting them in
>   different tables but as both numbers can grow indefinitely, I couldn't
>   think of a way to do that without having an indefinite number of
>   tables.

It sounds like the user and group values are repeated in your table. If this is true, the usual thing to do would be to 'normalize' the data.  In this case, you could move the relationship between users and groups to a different table.

You haven't specified whether the user or the group is the most tied to the row in your current table, though I'll guess it's probably the user.

A table layout with users, groups, and data would usually look like:

```
data_table
data_id    data_col_1    data_col_2    user_id
1          1.2374        pancakes            2
2          8.2978        strawberries        1
3          78.001        hashbrowns          1
...

user_table
user_id    user_name     group_id
1          Travis        1
2          Melanie       1
3          John          3
...

group_table
group_id   group_name
1          sales
2          marketing
3          engineering
...
```

This assumes the property that you mentioned, where one user is a member of only one group.  If that property changed to allow users to join more than one group, you would delete the group_id column in the users table and create a new 'mapping' table with two columns: user_id and group_id

If your data is organized this way, then user names and group membership can change without modifying all matching rows in the data table.

Here is a more in-depth explanation of DB normalization:
https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/

Comment: Thank you, I thought about doing it like you suggested, but I thought that there should be a more efficient way to find a user if you also know his group than just searching all users. The normalization approach doesn't really help with that. But I'm probably overthinking this a lot by assuming that finding the user is way more inefficient than it actually is.

Comment: In the normalization approach, you could use both the group and user information, but you'd probably need millions of users and lots of groups to make it useful.

(1) Look in group table to get group id (2) Look in user table for users with that group (needs index) (3) Find the user id from the subset you found in step 2 (4) filter the data table by the user id